# what do flags -i and -t mean in terms of docker run?

Tags: docker

I am very new to Docker and also to Unix/Linux world. I have been using docker to build my images and spin up some containers and do understand the concept of containerization fairly well. However, sometimes I do see some people spinning up containers using flags like :

`docker run -i -t imagename`

I tried to understand the value of it and came across docker documentation here : https://docs.docker.com/v1.13/engine/reference/run/

and it has some very arcane explainations like

`-i:  Keep STDIN open even if not attached`

`-t: Allocate a pseudo-tty`

what does it even mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground

> -a=[]           : Attach to `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and/or `STDERR`
> -t              : Allocate a pseudo-tty
> --sig-proxy=true: Proxy all received signals to the process (non-TTY mode only)
> -i              : Keep STDIN open even if not attached

If you do not specify -a then Docker will attach to both stdout and stderr . You can specify to which of the three standard streams (STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR) you’d like to connect instead, as in:

```
$ docker run -a stdin -a stdout -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together in order to allocate a tty for the container process.
-i -t is often written -it as you’ll see in later examples.
Specifying -t is forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe.

Comment: you seem to have finished your answer midsentence. What comes after 'as in:'?